# Formula for calculating parking time

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I can't seem to come up with a formula for calculating how much time I need to pay for.

Parking is free between $8PM - 6AM$.

I know the current time (parking start time) and for how long the person wants to park for. (The formula doesn't have to take into account seconds, just hours and minutes).

So examples:

- Parking from $5AM$ to $9PM$ is $14$ hours. (I get the correct value).
- Parking from $6PM$ to $7AM$ is $3$ hours. (This is the problematic case I can't solve).

Anyone nice enough to help me out with a formula, knowing the above $4$ variables (also that a day is 24 hours long).

Comment: Just as a thought, I'd imagine converting to a 24-hour system might be helpful.

Comment: I'm using 24 hours, and converting hours to minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Say the parking takes place from time $t_1$ to time $t_2$, where $t_1$ and $t_2$ are integers between $0$ and $24$. The number of free hours in the morning is equal to $\max\{6-t_1, 0\}$, while the number of free hours in the evening is $\max \{t_2 - 20, 0\}$. The total number of hours spent parking is $t_2 - t_1$, meaning the driver must pay for
$$t_2 - t_1 - \max\{6-t_1, 0\} -\max\{t_2 - 20, 0\}$$hours.

Comment: I might be doing something wrong, but I don't get the correct value for: t1 = 1080, t2 = 420. max{6-t1,0} = 0, max{t2-20,0} = 0.